# How to improve the program coding

Tags: c#

I am a C# developer. Still learning. I had not learn all the features of C# 2.0 and now the new version of c# is being released. how do we cope up with this.what is the best option to cope up with the latest programming skills.

Comment: Might help to be a little more specific? Are you talking about learning programming skills in general, or C# skills? Different learning styles suit different people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Steve M said: Read. But don't stop there. You also have to write.

First: Write Code. Try out the stuff you read about. Look at open source software and how things are done by others. Try those new techniques out.

Second: Write text. Write a blog post or whatever on how to do something. You had a problem and you solved it, now write down what the problem was, what ideas for solutions you had and what solution you picked for which reasons. Get people to comment, get peer review of your own thinking that way.

Comment: I completely agree with both of these items. StackOverflow is also a great place to learn: browse questions, answer questions, get flamed for not knowing enough about a subject... it all makes you a better developer.

Answer (score 4):

1. Read good quality code.  Locate other projects (open source or proprietary projects within your organizations) and look for how other engineers have approached particular issues.  Look for idioms, design patterns, styles that you find particularly good and adopt them in your coding practices.
2. Concentrate on the basics.  Sure knowing how to perform a particular operation best in C# is good, but knowing how and when to abstract, avoiding duplication, following style rules, and giving your identifiers appropriate names are more important skills.  These are also more valuable because you can apply them to any language.
3. Improve your code.  When you find in code something complicated or suboptimal try to think of a better way to write it.  For instance, if you write a lot of boilerplate code, examine how you can use abstraction mechanisms, like subroutines, methods, or classes, to avoid the code duplication.  If an expression is particularly long, think whether putting some of it into a separate function can increase its readability.
4. Use tools.  There are tools, like FindBugs, that can locate suboptimal or downright wrong code constructs.  Make it a habit to have your code pass cleanly through these tools, and also from your compiler's highest warning setting.
5. Have your code reviewed.  Find a mentor and have him or her review your code.  Be ready to accept criticism and learn from this experience.  Later repay this favor to the community by acting as a mentor.

Answer (score 3):

A good method to learn is to see what has changed in the language specifications and try them out yourself with small programs. Search some examples, try them, change them and see the results. There will be a time when you do some "real" work when you'll remember that stuff and think "that might actually help here"

Answer (score 2):

There are no magic tricks or secret ninja-methods. If you want to be good programmer, *work*. *Work a lot and hard*.

Book reading will not make you a professional if you don't use new knowledge in practice. Don't worry if you don't know all nifty features of .NET X.Y.Z. Work hard, try to solve different problems, ask your boss to give you different tasks and you will succeed. It's hard, but it's the only way to go. Work + learn at the free time and you will become professional.

But don't rush, remember that professionalism comes at a price - you can't be proficient at many different fields of work at once. Choose some technology that you like and can give you money, and go along with it. You *will feel* when time for changes comes.

Answer (score 1):

Read, read and when you're done reading, read some more. Reading also helps.

But seriously, sign up to relevant mailing lists and RSS feeds so that you can be updated as things happen.

Comment: @The reader of this post: Also, don't forget to write code for yourself. :3

Answer (score 1):

1) I try to get involved with my **local user groups** for c# it would be a Microsoft Technical User group

http://www.microsoft.com/communities/usergroups/default.mspx

They are usually a bunch of like minded individuals who want to learn about the new features in certain tools.

Microsoft are generally very good at helping to fund these groups and talks and seminars are held frequently. Often with the developer who created the tools you want to learn more about.

2) Get some **RSS Feeds/News letters** to c# sites such as [C# Corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/) or [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/)
They are usually the places

3) Oh and as mentioned by others, **read a LOT and try stuff out**. It's not easy to keep up with the new features but read about them, try them out on small little stand alone projects and have fun with them. 
I don't know about you but I derive great satisfaction from getting something new and cool to work.

As the Pragmatic programmers would say, improve your tool belt all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Read good code.

Pick an open source project you support. Start going through it on a regular basis, learning how it works by actually reading the code.

Answer (score 1):

the only way to learn to code, is to code... you become a *better* coder by observing people better than you.

Don't worry too much about new features in a languae, be aware of them sure, but concentrate on the core language

Answer (score 1):

It is useful to keep up with technologies, but even more useful to learn timeless skills that will apply whatever development tools you use.

To that end, I recommend reading Code Complete, and then some of the other classic programming books.

The other thing is just to keep on coding. My experience is that you'll pick up specific technologies as and when you need them. Sometimes you'll do this by looking at other people's code, sometimes by reading an interesting article or book, sometimes by going on a course. But however you do it, you'll find the tools you need when you need them.